# Xcode 8/Swift 3: Reset all variables to initial values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

When a `gameOver()` function is triggered, I would like all variables to reset to their original, unchanged values (as in, the values that are assigned in the ViewController file) when a user presses a **Restart** button. How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the specific variables you have, one solution would be to create a struct with the fixed initial values and assign those to your active game variables in the Restart function.

Answer (score 1):

You can define a function that reset the variables to the default value like this :

```
func resetGame(){
    score = 0 // or default value
    life = 3 // or default value
    //.... and so on
}
```

Assume the restart button are connected to this function

```
@IBAction func restartGame(sender: UIButton){
   gameOver()
   resetGame()
}
```

you can call this function after calling gameOver() inside the restart button function.

If your question is about how to declare default values you can use struct as Jay said like this :

```
struct DefaultValues {
    let score = 0
    let lifes = 3
    let level = 1
}
```

and resetGame() will be like this :

```
func resetGame(){
    score = DefaultValues().score
    life = DefaultValues().life
    level = DefaultValues().devel
}
```